# MYSQL PHP Query: Joining on more than one field

Tags: mysql, join

My table scheme for a social network site is as follows:

```
users
id|username
1|bob
2|mary
3|ken

userinfo
id|userid|handle|description
1|1|bobbie|student
2|2|Mary1|programmer

network
id|inviterid|invitedid|status
1|1|2|2
2|1|3|2
```

When one person invites another to join his/her network, an entry is made into the network table with status 1.  If the request is accepted, the status goes to 2.  So far so good.

However, I'm having trouble listing out members of someone's network while joining with other tables since in effect I have to join on more than one field since the person can either be the inviter or the invited.

Here is query to get members of network

```
//$id = id of logged in user
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `network` n
LEFT JOIN `userinfo` ui
on n.invitedid= ui.userid OR n.inviterid = ui.userid
LEFT JOIN`users` u
on n.invitedid= u.id OR n.inviterid = n.id
WHERE status='2'
```

Not all users have userinfo records as not everyone has filled out a profile.  But I want to get these as well.

Results of Query for Bob's network ie $id=1:

```
Bob student
Mary student
Bob programmer
Mary programmer
```

Note it includes bob even though he should be excluded, uses Bob's info for Mary and excludes Ken cause he has no userinfo record.

Above query gives multiple records for users with profiles, records for the logged in user and excludes any without profile.  I want to exclude logged in user and then one record for each member of his/her network including members without profiles.

Update:

changing WHERE to following excludes user's own profiles which helps a bit but still excludes members without profiles:

```
WHERE status = '2' AND ui.userid <> '$id'
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide relevant sample data and desired output?

Comment: see sample data and output above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `network` n
LEFT JOIN `userinfo` ui
on n.invitedid= ui.userid OR n.inviterid = ui.userid
RIGHT JOIN`users` u
on n.invitedid= u.id OR n.inviterid = n.id
WHERE status='2'
```

Comment: This still excludes anyone without entry in userinfo and gives multiple records for one relationship